# Set default route for taxonomy

Tags: bolt-cms

In `routing.yml` I have defined a new route for categories:

```
categories:
    path: '/{slug}/'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::taxonomy'
        taxonomytype: categories
```

But Bolt still generates url for categories following the general pattern:

```
taxonomylink:
    path: '/{taxonomytype}/{slug}'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::taxonomy'
    requirements:
        taxonomytype: 'Bolt\Controllers\Routing::getAnyTaxonomyTypeRequirement'
```

*E.g.*: for category `van-gogh` the generated url is `/categories/van-gogh`, but I would like to generate urls like `/van-gogh`. I would like to leave unchanged other taxonomy types: `/tags/hermitage` should not become `/hermitage`, but it should stay the same.

How can I have Bolt do this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Set up an early route similar to this:

```
taxonomybinding:
    path: '/{taxonomytype}'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::taxonomy'
    requirements:
        taxonomytype: 'Bolt\Controllers\Routing::getAnyTaxonomyTypeRequirement'
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. Maybe I didn't explain the problem well, I've reworked the question a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Set the taxonomytype to `category` instead of `categories`.

PS You should define some requirements, otherwise `/hermitage` would match, too, resulting in an error, because there is no category with that slug.